# Visual Studio Online Release Management URL with a Stand Alone Server

Tags: deployment, azure-devops

We have a Visual Studio Online project and I'm able to get everything pretty setup... However while installing the Microsoft Deployment Agent on our web server (NOT AZURE) it's asking for a Release Management Server URL, which I have (from the admin GUI)

https://SOMETHINGINAMED.vsrm.visualstudio.com:443/defaultcollection

This fails when I type it in... How do I set up the deploy agent?

Answer (score 2):

Release Management as part of VSO currently only supports Azure agent less deployments with DSC or Powershell.

You will need to install a full Release Management server in an Azure VM or locally to get Agent deployments.

Check out the connect() videos on http://visualstudio.com for the RM features that are available.